# Line drop of a second TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, line, android-relativelayout

I have two textview in a same line, the two textview do not have static content, the problem comes when the second textview is loaded with data, this takes the second line but not from the left completely.

The **code** is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="uno"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
            android:textColor="@color/from"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="titulo"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
            android:textColor="@color/from"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
           />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The picture**:
[image]

Comment: the problem is that you are using a RelativeLayout AND you are using properties on your second TextView saying that it will be to the right of the first one but at the same time to the left.

Comment: @Raykud  Please help me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

if you really must keep your `RelativeLayout` I would suggest replacing it as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="uno"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
        android:textColor="@color/from"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="titulo"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
        android:textColor="@color/from"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/add"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Explanation: I removed the aligns on the first `TextView` as `alignParentStart` is the same as `alignParentLeft` and by default in a `RelativeLayout` it should align to the top (also why removed `alignParentTop`) and left unless you are using RTL; Removed the `alignParentTop`because as you are using a `RelativeLayout`it will overlap the first `TextView`, also removed the `layout_toRightOf`(`layout_toEndOf`) on the second as that means it will start drawing text from where the first one ends, removed the margin because you want it be all the way left and removed `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_toLeftOf`  as previously mentioned.

Now if you do not need a `RelativeLayout` I would suggest using a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation instead.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- insert your code here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok I use LinearLayout. But I need the textview is in the same line so use relativelayout, one textview is filled with the name and the other textview with a title

Comment: Please see the image express what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have your second `TextView`'s text start to the left of the first, but then wrap below it if there's a second line.

This is not possible out-of-the-box using `TextView`, regardless of whether your parent view is a `RelativeLayout`, a `LinearLayout`, or anything else.

Probably the best solution is to simply use a single `TextView` and to combine the text in your Java code before you set it to the `TextView`s. In other words, instead of writing something like:

```
String text1 = "first part";
String text2 = "of the text I want to put in my layout";
textView1.setText(text1);
textView2.setText(text2);
```

Write this:

```
String text1 = "first part";
String text2 = "of the text I want to put in my layout";
textView.setText(text1 + " " + text2);
```

Even better, consider using [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) instead of concatenating your text manually:

```
String text1 = "first part";
String text2 = "of the text I want to put in my layout";
textView.setText(getString(R.string.mystring, text1, text2));
```

Comment: If you need to color the two parts differently, but put them in the same TextView, you will need to use `TextAppearanceSpan`... you should be able to find info on that in other questions/answers on this site.

Comment: Would you be so kind to leave me an example, thank you